# counting how much time has passed AngularJS/MongoDB

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

In model mongoose I did:

```
comments: [{ text: String, 
authorID: {type : Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}, 
name: String,
created: { type: Date, default: Date.now } }],
```

After creating the document, it looks like this:

```
 "comments" : [ 
    {
        "name" : "bartlomiej",
        "authorID" : ObjectId("5a1db9e8db97d318ac70715d"),
        "text" : "siema",
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a1df3708284fd2ecc900b4b"),
        "created" : ISODate("2017-11-28T23:38:24.910Z")
     }
```

And I now have a question on how to create a function that will count how much time has elapsed since adding a comment, using AngularJS.

Comment: Not clear what you're asking, what do you have done on the angular side of the code where are you stuck?  can you fetch the data from the server fine?  Does the date show up in JS as a valid date object or unix timestamp? not clear where you're stuck.

Comment: If you know the 'created' time, then all you need is "now - created" to give you that. You always know what "now" is right?? lol.

Comment: The problem is that value saved in db is in string , if I will create new variable with var date = new Date(), i can't make for example var elapsed = new Date - {{item.current}}; because item.current is in string and new Date is in object so how can another make counting how much time has passed

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use **directives** like [angular-timeago](https://github.com/yaru22/angular-timeago) it's easy to use and has a good documentation easy to follow.